# Full screen tkinter canvas python

Tags: python, tkinter, fullscreen, tkinter-canvas

Hello how can I make a full screen `tkinter.Canvas`? Can you help me? This is my code:

```
import tkinter
import datetime
import sys
import os

uvodcanvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=400,height=200,bg="white")
uvodcanvas.pack()

tkinter.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to make your main window full-screen, then configure the canvas to occupy the whole main window:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True) # make main window full-screen

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg='white', highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True) # configure canvas to occupy the whole main window

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `root.attributes` to fullscreen.
The following example shows how to toggle from fullscreen to a sized window, and vice-versa, upon pressing the `Escape` key

```
import tkinter as tk

def toggle_fs(dummy=None):
    state = False if root.attributes('-fullscreen') else True
    root.attributes('-fullscreen', state)
    if not state:
        root.geometry('300x300+100+100')

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Canvas(root, bg='cyan').pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

root.bind('<Escape>', toggle_fs)

root.mainloop()
```